# Preserve Node-integer when building igraph graph and put clustering into it

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph, network-analysis

I have got a graph g which I loaded using numbered edges and then  applied the community_infomap() method to get a clustering. Please see my code below for info.

What I want to have is a dataframe/series where I have the original edge-list entities as index, then the cluster number (infmap_object.membership) that infomap put it in and (optionally the count of edges it is part of).

Is there a function or any way that allows for this? Or can I set the graph creation to preserve original IDs instead of just proxying them to an increasing number?

Code:

```
import igraph as ig

#edges = [(node1, node2, weight), ...]

g = ig.Graph.TupleList(edges, weights=True)

infmap = g.community_infomap(edge_weights = g.es["weight"])

df_edges = infmap.get_edges_dataframe() --> # df_edges["key1"] != edges[0]["key1"], iGraph reset the numbers I gave the nodes
```